# JavaScript automatic slideshow, trying to get working buttons

Tags: javascript, button, slideshow

my very first post on here!

I'm working on a website, which has a full screen slideshow landing page. It changes image every few seconds, and has small dots at the side of the page, to indicate which image is currently active.
It's all working great so far, but I'd like to make the small dots clickable, and change to the respective image.

As I am still very new at coding, I haven't been able to find a solution that works. Every image slider I can find online is either manual ones, with clickable buttons, or automatic ones, with no buttons at all.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
        <div id="slide1" class="mySlides fade">Image 1</div>
        <div id="slide2" class="mySlides fade">Image 2</div>
        <div id="slide3" class="mySlides fade">Image 3</div>
        <div id="dotContainer">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </div>          
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mySlides{
    display: none;  
}

#slideshow{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #717171;
}

#dotContainer{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 98%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dot{
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 6px 15px 6px 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.activeDot{
    background-color: rgba(34,34,34, 0.7);
}

.fade{
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade{
    from{
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides();

    function showSlides(){
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

        for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > slides.length){
            slideIndex = 1;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++){
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" activeDot", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " activeDot";
        setTimeout(showSlides, 3000);       
    }
```

You can see it in action here: [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewras93/0wLgdoru/9/)

All help is very much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/0wLgdoru/37/

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" activeDot", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " activeDot";

}

function dotClickHandler(e) {
clearInterval(intervalId);
    var activeDotIndex = this.getAttribute("slideDot");
    slideIndex = activeDotIndex - 1;
    showSlides();
    intervalId =  setInterval(showSlides, 3000);
}
var dotNode = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
for (var i=0;i<dotNode.length;i++) {
    dotNode[i].addEventListener("click", dotClickHandler);
}

var intervalId =  setInterval(showSlides, 3000);
```

```css
.mySlides{
 display: none;  
}

#slideshow{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 position: relative;
  background-color: #717171;
}

#dotContainer{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 98%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dot{
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 margin: 6px 15px 6px 0;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: block;
 transition: 0.6s;
}

.activeDot{
 background-color: rgba(34,34,34, 0.7);
}

.fade{
 animation-name: fade;
 animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade{
 from{
  opacity: 0.4;
 }
 to{
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
   <div id="slide1" class="mySlides fade">Image 1</div>
   <div id="slide2" class="mySlides fade">Image 2</div>
   <div id="slide3" class="mySlides fade">Image 3</div>
   <div id="dotContainer">
    <span class="dot" slideDot="1"></span>
    <span class="dot" slideDot="2"></span>
    <span class="dot" slideDot="3"></span>
   </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? It doesn't seem to work, even if I run it through your code snippet

Comment: I think that you are struggling with `slider dot button` right ? if yes then It working properly in above snippet and if no, then what is your actual requirement?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I get this error message however, when I try to run the code:
{
  "message": "Object doesn't support property or method 'Symbol.iterator'",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 96,
  "colno": 1
}

Comment: I do not why It is not working at your end, I just updated `fiddle` link for same code  in my answer.

Comment: That's weird, it's not working on my end at all. Just stuck at the first image, it doesn't even slide anymore

Comment: Yes definetly it is weird, I am also not able to figuring out why it is not working at your end.

Comment: Last thing I would suggest to you that  see  my code and implement same manually.

Comment: Seems to be a browser issue, it's working on Google Chrome. Thanks for your help, I'll try to see if I can find a fix for the browser issue now!

Comment: I'm using Edge. Is there another way to write the "for of loop"? That seems to be the problem when running on Edge, as far as I can tell

Comment: Yes I updated my answer you can use normal `for loop` function rather than `for of`.

Comment: Perfect, it works now! Thank you so much for your help, and quick response time, really appreciate it!